# Exchange: dont save if nothing has been changed?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

I'm admin in a company where we have pretty much 'digital-non-native'-workers, that simply dont get used to the computer way of thinking. One problem is: they always press "save" to close an entry in the shared exchange calender, and, well, they've grown up with pen and paper office and often feel overstrained if i try to explain. They dont want to understand 'that much detail' of computers (machine has to work and that is my problem :D)

But i'd like to see what was the last *real* change to an exchange entry without logging the whole calendar. Is there a way to dont let outlook save something to the calender if nothing has been changed?